# How to fix <delete> and arrow keys in ansi-term on macOS

Tags: key-bindings, osx, ansi-term

I'm running emacs on macOS, and I've run into problems with `ansi-term`. Using bash itself works fine, but as soon as I run a simple application with a command line interface, my `<delete>` and arrow keys break.

Instead of the usual delete behaviour, emacs prints `^h`, and instead of moving in the direction indicated by the arrow keys, emacs prints `^[OA`, `^[OB`, `^[OC`, and `^[OD`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution. `C-c C-j` switches the terminal from `term-char-mode` to `term-line-mode`, and fixes the behaviour inside the application. Once I'm finished with the application, `C-c C-k` switches the terminal back to `term-char-mode`.

Info found [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Term-Mode.html).